# Not able to import pymongo though it's installed to its latest version

Tags: ubuntu

```
>>> import pymongo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/hussain/pymongo.py", line 3, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'MongoClient'
```

Comment: Can you please describe how you installed `pymongo`?

Comment: hey!!
actually i was saving my file as pymongo.py that's y it was creating a prob.
So it was my mistake :D